# How to install the drivers for a samsung ml-1670?

Tags: drivers, printing

I have just re-installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS via internet but I'm not able to print anything with my Laser Printer SAMSUNG ML-1670.

Where or how I can find and install the proper driver for Ubuntu??

Comment: I can recommend the bchemnet repository. I have a ML-1670 myself here too and it works perfectly with these slightly modified Samsung software packages. http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/

Answer (score 4):

Unless [this bug hasn't been fixed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/1102001), you only need to:

1. From the Printers dialogue, select Add Printer.
2. Select "Samsung ML-1670" from the devices list (connected via USB)
3. Select "Select printer from database" and "Samsung (recommended)"
4. Select "ML-1660 (recommended)" from the Models, and "Samsung ML-1660, 2.0.0 [en] (recommended)" from Drivers
5. Click through and Apply
6. Print a test page

If it doesn't work, install the `printer-driver-splix` package, settings must be monocrome instead of color and max. 600dpi.

Comment: Unfortunately, following these instructions on Ubuntu 14.04 leads to printing a page which says "INTERNAL ERROR - Please use the proper driver".

Comment: Anyway, Launchpad bug linked above contains a workaround which works.

Answer (score 3):

Download drivers from this page: http://www.samsung.com/pk/support/model/ML-1675/XSG-downloads, extract them and install drivers with:

```
sudo ./install-printer.sh
```

`cd` into `/usr/lib/cups/filter`.

If the link `rastertosplc` (not `rastertospl`) doesn’t exist, add symbolic link to `/opt/smfp-common/printer/bin/rastertospl` with:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/smfp-common/printer/bin/rastertospl rastertosplc
```

then you will find ML1670 in database of printers in system settings.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the Samsung ML-1670 Linux driver available for download, firstly at the Samsung support web, and now as the universal printer driver for Linux, [here](http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/DR/201510/20151028145757854/uld_v1.00.36_00.91.tar.gz)

Comment: I don't think it needs to have worked 5 years ago to help current and future visitors...

Comment: I have the original ML-1670 Linux driver and the original ML-1670 Smart Panel for Linux too. Thanks for censoring my answers, but the truth is out there, this driver was available since 2013 so no need to use the ML-1660 or ML-1675 drivers neither tricks but the original driver.