# I think my laptop have the drivers but its not printing

Tags: drivers, printing

This is my first time in Ubuntu printing problem.
I have downloaded the drivers from the official site, and I don't know whether I installed it correctly with terminal, it didn't output anything.
I have plug in the printer USB it said its connecting and it got connected also, but when I try to print anything it say "Sending data to the printer and Completed printing" but my printer didn't move, didn't print anything.
I have try to do install additional drivers but it says no driver.
I again try to add it by manually it open a bunch of list of drivers.
Choose from the database
My printer is Samsung SCX-4521F
Ubuntu:20.04.2 LTS

Comment: Hey Arsh Ergon! Can you please [edit] your question and add information regarding how you installed the driver?

Comment: Hey Random person I figure out it by myself. It was my mistake.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install the drivers for a samsung ml-1670?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/354461/how-to-install-the-drivers-for-a-samsung-ml-1670)

Answer (score 0):

I got it what I was using wrong.
Firstly after some research I got to know that Ubuntu already come with many drivers install.
When I was manually adding my printer, it was showing the recommend printer name, and it's driver.. which is wrong.
In the recommend drivers I search for my printer model name and I found it, I select it and boom! It works.

Comment: Hey Arsh Ergon! It would be nice if you can add some screenshots in your answer :)